# How to add package version number in custom Laravel package

Tags: laravel, gitlab, composer-php

Instead of using

```
"require": {
 "vendor/custom package" : "master@dev"
}
```

I want to use

```
"require": {
 "vendor/custom package" : "^1.0.0"
}
```

I couldn't find a way to add version number to the package. when I enter "*" instead of "dev@master", composer can't find the package in gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://gitlab.com/your-org/custom_package"
    }
],
"require": {
    "vendor/custom_package": "1.0.*"
}
```

Comment: adding a verbal explanation is often helpful